# broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE

Tags: java, android, firebase

My phone is Samsung A2 having Os 8.1.0. When app is foreground or background notifications received but when app is in sleep mode then onMessageReceived not got called...so push notification not received.. it gives error like broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE

```
`public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends   FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG =   MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
public static Ringtone notificationRingtone=null;
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
}
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
  Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body1: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body2: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
```

}`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.